# Xamarin Native map point open infowindow by default

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mkmapview, google-maps-markers, mkannotation

Im loading a native map application (android,IOS) with a custom pin location and with a custom marker.What i need is when i load the map i need to open the map pin marker info window by default.

currently what is happening is when user tap the pin info then only the pin info window shows up.
I have seen some code there markerOpt1.showInfoWindow() there is no method like this.
As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows)  i know only one info window can pops up.In my scenario only one pin is there

Android implementation

```cs
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
{
    MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt1.SetPosition(new LatLng(50.379444, 2.773611));
    markerOpt1.SetTitle("Vimy Ridge");

    var bmDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker (BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueCyan);
    markerOpt1.InvokeIcon(bmDescriptor);

    map.AddMarker(markerOpt1);
}
```

I have write custom renders for Android native application markers and ios mkmapview how can i show up the information view when loading the map

Comment: I have added the expected result image
[Google Map Infor View](https://i.ibb.co/rx1McSk/To-Stack-Upload.png)

Comment: Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official sample of [customrenderers-map-pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-map-pin/), to open infowindow by default,

In `iOS`:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        //...

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

             //...
             //add MapLoaded  Event
             nativeMap.MapLoaded += NativeMap_MapLoaded;
        }
    }
```

And in NativeMap_MapLoaded:

```
private void NativeMap_MapLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    annotationView.SetSelected(true,true);
}
```

In `Android`, try this:

```
protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
{
    base.OnMapReady(map);


    MarkerOptions markerOpt1 = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt1.SetPosition(new LatLng(50.379444, 2.773611));
    markerOpt1.SetTitle("Vimy Ridge");

    var bmDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueCyan);

    Marker marker =  map.AddMarker(markerOpt1);
    marker.ShowInfoWindow();
}
```